# Can't find CSS rule that is declaring the width of <body>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on some HTML / CSS stuff and for some reason, I have a stray element that is overflowing my body and causing horizontal scroll bars.  Before you say it, I know this is a pretty n00b sounding mistake.  I typically don't have issues like this but I could really use a second set of eyes.

http://easterndancer.com.s66112.gridserver.com/

Can you find the element that's causing the scrolling overflow (horizontal)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's this:

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-primary-navigation-1">
```

In FireBug, it shows that its position is WAAAAaaay over to the right.  It's related to the `left: 50%;` styling.  While fiddling with the code, disabling this removed the scroll bar.

Comment: Excellent catch my friend.  That's actually a cool hack to force the navigation to center fluidly.  Anyway, it wasn't doing that before and then it started to :/  "Overflow: hidden" on the footer should take care of that!

Comment: What is all that hacking for anyway? I see a horizontal ul-nav menu in a fixed width container with defined elements!?

Comment: @Kissaki - I would explain but it would be a long story :/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
<body style="overflow-x:hidden;" class="home page page-id-27 page-template page-template-home-php">
```

Comment: good catch.  +1 for you, but Surreal Dreams (above) is "more right" it was definitely the footer nav, so I can just overflow:hidden that baby :)

Answer (score 1):

Using process of elimination (adding `display: none` to `div`'s) it is the menu items in `#menu-primary-navigation-1`